# Edimax PS-1210 MFn & HP Photosmart C4180 Scanning Problem

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp, scanner, xsane

I have successfully installed a HP Photosmart C4180 using an Edimax Print Server (PS-1210MFn) in Ubuntu 12.04 via the CUPS configuration.The printer is working perfectly with print server on Ubuntu,but the scanner is not discoverable by XSane OR Ubuntu's Simple Scan program.Do you know what can I do in order to make work under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### scanner support by HP

Your photosmart all-in-one via CUPS is in-fact using the HPLIP driver from HP themselves. i.e. this is already installed in 12.04 by default.

Looking at the compatibility page for your printer:

- http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/photosmart.html

[image: print]

Your printer is not supported by this driver for network printing.

There is a `yes` value for USB - that I'm afraid is the best that you can achieve with your printer.

### scanner support via SANE

Looking at the SANE website:

- http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-HEWLETT-PACKARD

Your scanner part of this all-in-one is not in-fact directly supported through the SANE project.